# how to copy a pointer's value to an simple variable inside a constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, obfuscation, constexpr, compile-time

i try to make this code work. I want make the constructor  accept a pointer to function, then copy the value of the pointer to f and then xor with 1234. This  normally should run on compile time. Then when i want to get the function pointer it will call the un_xor() so i can get the original pointer.

```
typedef void (*func)();

class xorfunc
{
public:
    __int64 f;
    inline constexpr xorfunc(func function)
        : f(0)
    {
        f = (__int64)function;
        f ^= 1234;
    }

    const func un_xor() const {
        return (func)(f ^ 1234);
    }

};

#define OCB(my_func) []{ constexpr xorfunc expr(my_func); return expr; }().decrypt()

//and then i call it like this
void fun1() 
{
}

func ptr = OCB(fun1);
```

with this code i get these errors:
'expression did not evaluate to a constant' and 'expression must have a constant value'

what is the problem with this?
can anyone help me make it work?

Comment: [tag:obfuscation]?!? Sure?? What do you want to achieve with that? Smells like a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: I suppose because, you know, expression does not evaluate to a constant? The compiler doesn't know anything about functions' addresses at a compile time. Linker does, but this stage happens later.

Comment: @Suthiro then how string encryptions at compile time working?

Comment: The value of a string is a compile-time known constant. Address of a function is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. The reason is that the numerical value of a pointer (as obtained through a `reinterpret_cast`) is not a compile-time constant. The code may be running on a system without virtual memory (in which case loading it at any particular address is not guaranteed; it will be loaded somewhere that has enough space) or a system that is using address space randomization and so on. Even if the *system* can guarantee that a variable or function in your program will always have the same address, the *compiler* cannot; the linker has to concatenate the static sections from the various translation units that the program is made up from in order to determine the final layout. Any value that is only known at link time cannot participate in arbitrary compile-time computations.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So the only solution is to make a externally application to xor the offsets of the funtions after built?

Comment: @George I don't think this is a useful form of obfuscation. The solution is to just not do it.